# Grails: How to add Flexslider? or other libraries?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grails

I've been using grails for a while and I'd like to use [flexslider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) for it. I'm assuming that the flexslider js files should be put under this directory:

/myProject/web-app/js/FlexSlider-1.7

I am told that I cannot use this: `<g:javascript>` tag because it is only used for libraries such as YUI and prototype, so I assume that I'll have to use this: `<script src="">` I tried this so far:

`<script src="/web-app/js/FlexSlider-1.7/jquery.flexslider.js"/>`

But, it does not seem to work even when I've already set up flexislider in my gsp files. :( 
Any help on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Grails 1.3.7? If so, you need the Grails jQuery plugin installed. FlexSlider depends on the jQuery JavaScript library, and Grails by default uses Prototype (a different library)

See: http://grails.org/plugin/jquery

After you install the jQuery plugin and declare jQuery using g:javascript in the instructions above, you can type in:

```
<g:javascript library="FlexSlider-1.7/jquery.flexslider" />
```

(note how there is no .js at the end)